# Created a user pool client using Cognito Identity Provider Client SDK for JavaScript v3, but can't fetch token using (client_credentials) grant type

Tags: oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-nodejs, clientcredential

Created a user pool client using Cognito Identity Provider Client SDK for JavaScript v3
`npm install @aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider`.

The following code shows how I created the resources server and the user pool client, using the mentioned SDK...

```
let  poolName = 'UserPool';
const client =new CognitoIdentityProviderClient({
          region: process.env.COGNITO_AWS_REGION
      });
// create resource server
    const createResourceServerCommand = new CreateResourceServerCommand({
      Name: poolName,
      UserPoolId: UserPool.Id,
      Identifier: 'https://localhost:8080/api/v2',
      Scopes: [
        {
          ScopeName: 'access',
          ScopeDescription: 'General access to API'
        }
      ]
    });

const { ResourceServer } = await client.send(createResourceServerCommand);
// create the user pool client
const createUserPoolClientCommand = new CreateUserPoolClientCommand({
      ClientName: 'Default',
      UserPoolId: UserPool.Id,
      ExplicitAuthFlows: ['USER_PASSWORD_AUTH'],
      GenerateSecret: true,
      AllowedOAuthFlows: ['client_credentials'],
      SupportedIdentityProviders: ['COGNITO'],
      AllowedOAuthScopes: [ 'https://localhost:8080/api/v2/access' ]
    });
   const { UserPoolClient } = await client.send(createUserPoolClientCommand);
```

...but, I can't fetch tokens using the grant type **client_credentials**. Therefore getting the following error.

```
{
  "error": "invalid_grant"
}
```

However, if I use AWS console to navigate to the *user pool >  Client > Edit the hosted UI* and **click on the save button without making any changes**...[image]

... I am able to fetch a token using the **client_credentials** grant type.

Is there any setting that I might be missing in the above code that AWS console is setting? I need the following code to automate the creation of user pools.

Answer (score 1):

When I switched to the old I noticed this notification[image]

Apparently, Oauth flows are not enabled by default. Hence adding the following attribute to the **CreateUserPoolClientCommandInput** object `AllowedOAuthFlowsUserPoolClient: true` enables it. Hope this helps some newbie like me out there.